# get_term_link is Ending to single.php

Tags: theme-development, single, advanced-taxonomy-queries, terms

I have a template like this:

1. page-movie.php
2. taxonomy-movie.php
3. taxonomy.php

and I am using the `get_term_link()` at `page-movie.php` to list and link from the indexed page into List of all Custom Post Types under that term in `taxonomy-movie.php` but this is ending in `single.php` page when user click on one of the listed terms!

```
<?php
    $tax = 'movieTax';
    $args = array(
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $tax_terms = get_terms($tax, $args);
    foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
    echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name. '(' . $tax_term->count .')' .'</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

This was working fine for me untill few hours ago and I just tried to fix on issue on counting the CPT's under tax term by adding this ti Taxonomy regiter function:

```
 'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
 'query_var'             => true,
```

and after that the links ended on single.php!
Then I removed the added code but still getting same issue!

Comment: `$taxonomy` is undefined in `get_term_link()`

Answer (score 2):

This sort of error that happens out of the blue like that tends to be related to the Database, so the only thing here that I could think of would be that your `global $wp_rewrite` got messed up by some plugin on something.

Try to refresh your permalinks by going to the admin page: "Settings" > "Permalinks" and hitting save, I think this might solve your problem.

If not provide us with the output you are getting on the `get_term_link` method.